# exec issue with netstat and lsof

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, shell

I want to check if a certain tunnel exists from inside PHP using (any of these commands):

```
$(which lsof) -i -n | grep ssh
$(which netstat) -a | grep "localhost:ssh"
```

The issue is that when I run the commands in the shell everything is fine but from php running them like:

```
$reply = exec(CMD);
```

always return nothing.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `$(which lsof)` instead of `lsof`? `which` will tell you which executable would be run if you didn't include a path anyway.

Comment: @moopet out of habit for exec calls. "which" shouldn't do any harm in this very case.

Comment: But why do you have that habit in exec calls? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect stderr to stdout and get the `$output` and `$return_var`. To do that, change your exec() call like this:

```
exec('$(which lsof) -i -n | grep ssh 2>&1', $output, $return_var);

var_dump($return_var);
var_dump($output);
```

More info about exec here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php (have a look at `$output` and `$return_var` parameters).

Comment: Thanks. The results for your code:
int(1)
array(0) {
}

Comment: Ok in other words it does not return anything. I've just tested it, it works for me. Can you try to run this script with php cli? (run `php -a` then paste your code). Other question: what's your php version and is safe_mode enabled?

Comment: Works fine (with php -a): php > var_dump($return_var);
int(0)
php > var_dump($output);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(112) "ssh       20535 unknown    3u  IPv4 5236207      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.100:36330->138.201.117.XXX:ssh (ESTABLISHED)"
}

php -v returns

PHP 7.0.8-3ubuntu3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-3ubuntu3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies and about safe mode: php -i | grep safe
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off

Comment: Ok so I think it's a problem about php-fpm (if nginx) or mod_php (if apache). Maybe your http user (usually www-data) cannot run this kind of command? (php cli is != php for your web server -> different user, different version, different behavior...)

Comment: That's what i thought too, added www-data in sudoers list for netstat/lsof path but still without success.

Comment: Found the issue, i moved everything to a sh file and sudo -u www-data ./check_ssh.sh doesn't return anything, but using -u on my username does. So it is fully a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is more to do with how PHP interprets your command...

In this case (assuming instead of CMD you write same command you try in shell), it would try to:
$reply = exec(**$(which lsof)** -i -n | grep ssh);
means it would try to substitute the bold part as a PHP variable, and try to execute the resultant string. As the output of "-i -n |grep ssh" is null, so you get nothing as a result.

I would suggest you to instead:

```
$lsof = exec(which lsof);
$reply = exec($lsof -i -n | grep ssh);
```